# Is there a regular expression technique that will match a zip code with one pair of digits transposed?

Tags: regex, oracle

Preferably using Oracle syntax, I need to match US zip codes (5 digit numeric) where one pair of digits have been transposed.

Can this be done with a regular expression?

If so, what would that regex look like?

Edit:

Make that transposition of two consecutive digits;

12345 = 12345 or 12354 or 12435 or 13245 or 21345

Comment: an example would be better..

Comment: Let's say your given zip code is 12345, then you would want to match 21345 or 52341 or 13245 but not 12345 or 54321?

Comment: Make that transposition of two consecutive digits;

12345 = 12345 or 12354 or 12435 or 13245 or 21345

Comment: The more I think about it, the less I think regexes are suitable for this task (unless you want to spell out all possible matches: `^(12345|21345|13245|12435|12354)$`)...

Comment: Since I am by no means proficient at regexes, I thought I would ask. I could get close by looking for a 2 digit difference (where any two digits are different) and the numeric difference is divisible by 9. Or by walking the 5 digits one at a time and looking at the digit before & after.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about oracle but you may append your string w/ a known string like `match 12345` and use this pattern:

```
\b((\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d))\b(?=.*?match: (?:\2\3\4\6\5|\2\3\5\4\6|\2\4\3\5\6|\3\2\4\5\6))
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/36)

Answer (score 2):

I respectfully submit that the real solution is to not allow bad data in in the first place, otherwise you will be trapped forever creating bizarre and difficult to maintain code to allow for any strange way the users (bless their hearts) enter it. Perhaps you can run a "cleanup" routine that fixes bad zips from time to time so your select code does not have to jump through hoops. That way, if someone else needs to use the data it is clean in the table and they won't have to jump through hoops either.

At a previous job we got a zipcode CD from the US Post Office quarterly and that data was loaded into tables.  The application that was on top of those tables referenced them at the point of data entry and made sure a valid zip was entered.  Maybe that is an option.

At my current job, we have a process where addresses are geocoded and besides getting the latitudes and longitudes, the process returns addresses corrected for the proper US Post Office format, including fixed zip codes. Sweet!

A little searching would also reveal services that would let you validate address as they are entered by interfacing with a web service or something like that.

The main point is, you have issues at a higher level that should address the problem.    If the data is coming from a closed vendor's system there should be a process for correcting bad zips when they are found by reporting to the source for fixing via an exception report of some sort.

Comment: Gary, I agree completely. Unfortunately this exercise involves getting data from an outside sources (as in many sources), cleaning it up as best we can so that it will pass our internal checks which include validating zip code against city/state. The data eventually will be cleaned by a geocoding service, but I need to get it past basic level checks first.

Comment: I feel your pain as I've been there myself. Beware of transposed numbers matching a different, valid zip from another city/state though. You really need to test a zip in the context of it's city/state. Good luck!

Comment: Actually make sure your geocoding service returns a corrected zip based on the city/state (ours does). This check may not be needed at all!

Comment: I have the usps city/state/zip table, I use a jaro winkler fuzzy match on any city in the zip, if I get a reasonable hit I'm done, if not I get the best city using a fuzzy match in the state, and then i get the best zip for the city using a fuzzy match boosting the score when there is just one transposition. If I get close the geocoding software will clean it up later.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Gary's thoughts on this matter.  Also, I looked at alpha bravo's answer and this borrow's on this person's answer.

Assume that the subquery factoring clause results in a zip code which we are looking for a matching permutation (as you have identified).

I then create a zip code interface table (an unclean table we want to pick through records and check for matches).

I use a regexp replace approach as seen below:

```
SCOTT@tst> CREATE TABLE scott.zip_data_interface AS
  2  SELECT TO_CHAR(object_id) zip_code
  3  FROM all_objects
  4  WHERE object_id BETWEEN 50000 AND 59999
  5  /

Table created.
  1    WITH z_code AS (
  2          SELECT '53211' zip
  3            FROM dual
  4         )
  5  SELECT z_code.zip, zdi.zip_code
  6    FROM z_code
  7    JOIN (
  8          SELECT zip,
  9                 REGEXP_REPLACE(z_code.zip, '^(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)$', '\1\2\3\4\5') zip_perm
 10            FROM z_code
 11           UNION ALL
 12          SELECT zip,
 13                 REGEXP_REPLACE(z_code.zip, '^(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)$', '\2\1\3\4\5') zip_perm
 14            FROM z_code
 15           UNION ALL
 16          SELECT zip,
 17                 REGEXP_REPLACE(z_code.zip, '^(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)$', '\1\3\2\4\5') zip_perm
 18            FROM z_code
 19           UNION ALL
 20          SELECT zip,
 21                 REGEXP_REPLACE(z_code.zip, '^(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)$', '\1\2\4\3\5') zip_perm
 22            FROM z_code
 23           UNION ALL
 24          SELECT zip,
 25                 REGEXP_REPLACE(z_code.zip, '^(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)$', '\1\2\3\5\4') zip_perm
 26            FROM z_code
 27         ) zip_permutation
 28      ON z_code.zip = zip_permutation.zip
 29    JOIN zip_data_interface zdi
 30*     ON zip_permutation.zip_perm =zdi.zip_code
SCOTT@tst> /

ZIP   ZIP_CODE
===== ========================================
53211 52311
53211 53121
53211 53211
53211 53211
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to bail on the regex, and wrote a special purpose PL/SQL function. It seems to work.

Here is the function;

```
  FUNCTION CHECK_ZIP_TRANSPOSE(IN_ZIP1 VARCHAR2, IN_ZIP2 VARCHAR2) RETURN BINARY_INTEGER DETERMINISTIC
  AS
    TEMP_STRING VARCHAR2(100) := IN_ZIP1||IN_ZIP2;
    I BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
    TEMP_ZIP1 VARCHAR2(6) := '|' || SUBSTR(IN_ZIP1,1,5);
  BEGIN
    IF LENGTH(TEMP_STRING) != 10 OR 
       LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(TEMP_STRING, ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) IS NOT NULL
    THEN 
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
    IF MOD(ABS(TO_NUMBER(IN_ZIP1) - TO_NUMBER(IN_ZIP2)),9) != 0
    THEN
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
    TEMP_STRING := NULL;
    FOR I IN 2..5
    LOOP
      TEMP_STRING := TEMP_STRING || SUBSTR(TEMP_ZIP1,1,I-1) || SUBSTR(TEMP_ZIP1,I+1,1) || SUBSTR(TEMP_ZIP1,I,1) || SUBSTR(TEMP_ZIP1,I+2);
    END LOOP;
    IF INSTR(TEMP_STRING,IN_ZIP2) > 0
    THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSE
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  END CHECK_ZIP_TRANSPOSE;
```